# Remove quotes from JMeter variables in request body

Tags: jmeter, request

I am trying to generate POST request in Jmeter:
My Body Data looks like this:

```
{"query": "{getSingleArticle(id: ${art_id}){MatlDesc, ClassDesc}}"}
```

The resulting request is the this:

```
{"query": "{getSingleArticle(id: "123456789"){MatlDesc, ClassDesc}}"}
```

how do I get rid of the quotes around the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have quotes in variable value normally, so check if you can remove quotes in variable's definition/regex/csv record, if you can't use [__groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) to remove quotes before request:

```
${__groovy( vars.put("art_id"\,vars.get("art_id").replaceAll("\""\,"")) )}
```

Or use similar code inside [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)  which will be a child to request

```
vars.put("art_id"\,vars.get("art_id").replaceAll("\""\,""));
```

Comment: I am reading my variables from csv, there, they are strings, so I think that is why they come with quotes. Your second suggestion worked, thank you! How to use the first with groovy I did not understand, can you please add more details? Do you mind if I remove "\" from your answer before accepting it? Backslashes caused an error..

Comment: @MStikh you can put it before, for example as part of previous request name , BTW in CSV data Set it shouldn't by default add quotes, check if marking `Allow quoted data?` as false helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use [__strReplace() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) for this like:

```
${__strReplace(${art_id},",,)}
```

[image]

The function can be installed as a part of [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)